# Correct XSLT syntax for Google multilingual sitemaps/ xhtml:link

Tags: xml, xslt, sitemap

I have an XML sitemap for a multilingual site that follows [Google's specifications for multilingual sitemaps](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en) using the `xhtml:link` tags.

The syntax looks like this:

```
        <url>
          <loc>http://www.example.com/url-segment/</loc>
          <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/url-segment/" />
          <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="de" href="http://www.example.com/de/url-segment/" />
          <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.example.com/fr/url-segment/" />
          <lastmod>2016-08-09T00:41:57+12:00</lastmod>
          <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
          <priority>0.9</priority>
        </url>
```

I'm trying to make this human readable for the client using an XSLT template like this:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:urlset/sitemap:url">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:variable name="itemURL">
          <xsl:value-of select="sitemap:loc"/>
        </xsl:variable>
      </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(sitemap:priority*100,'%')"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(translate(substring(sitemap:changefreq, 1, 1),concat($lower, $upper),concat($upper, $lower)),substring(sitemap:changefreq, 2))"/>
     </td>
     <td>
       <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(sitemap:lastmod,0,11),concat(' ', substring(sitemap:lastmod,12,5)))"/>
     </td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Which works without the `xhtml:link` tags. But I'm not sure how to correctly reference the `xhtml:link` tags. I've tried something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xhtml:link">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:link@href"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="xhtml:link@hreflang"/>
    </td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But that's not working.

What is the correct XSLT syntax for looping through/ selecting `xhtml:link` tags in Google multilingual sitemaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get it to recognise/ reference the `xhtml:link` node using this code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xhtml:link">
```

In the end this approach worked for me:

```
<xsl:for-each select="./*[@rel='alternate']">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@hreflang"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the same thing as BaronGrivet (a sitemap with xhtml:link tags that displays nicely in a browser). I found an xsl template by Pedro Borges on [GitHub](https://github.com/pedroborges/xml-sitemap-stylesheet) that works quite nicely.

Rather than using `xsl:for-each` to loop through each xhtml link, that template uses `xsl:apply-templates` (apply-templates processes all of the child nodes of the current node}.

The key parts from Pedro’s template are:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body>
            …
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            …
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="sitemap:urlset">
    …
    <xsl:for-each select="sitemap:url">
        …
        <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:*"/>
        …
    </xsl:for-each>
    …
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xhtml:link">
    <xsl:variable name="altloc">
        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <p>
        Alt language version: 
        <a href="{$altloc}">
            <xsl:value-of select="@href"/> 
        </a> 
        –
        <xsl:if test="@hreflang">
            <xsl:value-of select="@hreflang"/> 
        </xsl:if> 
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

Pedro's template has a lot more capability than I need (e.g. can list videos), but it was easy enough to edit the template to do what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are already in `xhtml:link` node (in xsl:for-each). Use

```
<xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
```

and

```
<xsl:value-of select="@hreflang"/>
```